CORS preflight issue in HTTPS env. "cross-origin resource sharing error: preflight wildcard origin not allowed" when using withCredentials
Im experiencing a CORS issue after deploying my application to an HTTPS environment. The error is:
cross-origin resource sharing error preflight wildcard origin not allowed


In my local environment, where I have different subdomains on http, the setup works perfectly:
Backend (local): http://local.api.group.com:9090
Frontend (local): http://local.fe.group.com:3000

However, after deploying to QA using https, I get the CORS error:
Backend (QA): https://qa.api.group.com
Frontend (QA): https://qa.fe.group.com

In my Spring Boot backend, I have the following CORS configuration:
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins(
                        "https://qa.fe.group.com",
                        "http://local.fe.group.com"
                )
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "OPTIONS", "PATCH", "PUT", "DELETE", "HEAD")
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .allowCredentials(true)
                .allowPrivateNetwork(true)
                .allowedOriginPatterns(
                        "https://qa.fe.group.com",
                        "http://local.fe.group.com"
                );
    }
}

And on the frontend, I’m using Axios with withCredentials set to true:
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  withCredentials: true,
});


Why does the setup work perfectly in local (HTTP) but fails after
deploying in an HTTPS environment?

How can I configure my CORS settings to resolve the "preflight wildcard origin not allowed" error?

Does the problem lie in the use of allowCredentials(true) or the cookie settings for cross-subdomain requests?


I’ve already ensured that the frontend uses withCredentials and the backend sets allowCredentials(true) in the CORS config.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated!
